# Adding graphics2d to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, graphics2d

I'm new in java. I'm trying to make an asteroids clone game but I'm running into trouble.

I'm not sure how to add a graphics2d object back to the jframe. Any help would be appreciated. Also, I plan on adding alot more to this, so sorry if it looks a kinda goofy.
Currently the jframe draws but I don't get any objects inside.

Main Class

```
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Program extends JApplet
{
public void init()
{
    String[] s = new String[0];
    main(s);
};

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Launching Window");
    Window w = new Window();
    w.setSize(700, 600);
    w.setLocation(50,50);
    w.setVisible(true);
    w.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    System.out.println("Launching Game");
    Game g = new Game();

    while(g.play)
    {
        System.out.println("Looping");
        g.tick();
        w.repaint();
    };
}
};
```

Gui Stuff (not for sure if i need this or merge with game.java)

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Window extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel panel;

    public Window()
    {
        panel = new JPanel();
        add(panel);
    };

};
```

Game.java, main logic for program, not completely there yet

```
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Game implements KeyListener
{
    public static int xmax = 800;
    public static int ymax = 600;

    private LinkedList<Rock> rocks = new LinkedList();
    private LinkedList<Laser> lasers = new LinkedList();
    private Ship ship;

    private int score = 0;
    public boolean play = true;

    public Game()
    {
        ship = new Ship(xmax/2, ymax/2);    //Game objects
        rocks.add(new Rock(50, 50, 50));
    };

    public void reinit()
    {
        ship = null;
        rocks.clear();
        lasers.clear();
        score = 0;
    };

    public void tick()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < rocks.size(); i++)   //Check to see if bullets hit unit, remove that unit
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < lasers.size(); j++)
            {
                if(rocks.get(i).hit(rocks.get(j)))
                {
                    if(rocks.get(i).size > 20)  //if rocks bigger than 20 spawn some more rocks
                    {
                        rocks.add(new Rock(rocks.get(j).x, rocks.get(j).y, rocks.get(j).size/3));   //add three rocks on hit
                        rocks.add(new Rock(rocks.get(j).x, rocks.get(j).y, rocks.get(j).size/3));
                        rocks.add(new Rock(rocks.get(j).x, rocks.get(j).y, rocks.get(j).size/3));
                    };
                    rocks.remove(j);                                                                //remove hit rock
                    lasers.remove(i);                                                               //remove laser
                };
            };
        };

        for(int i = 0; i < rocks.size(); i++) //move units
        {
            rocks.get(i).tick();
        };

        for(int i = 0; i < lasers.size(); i++) //move bullets
        {
            lasers.get(i).tick();
        };

        ship.tick();
    };

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
            lasers.add(new Laser(ship.x, ship.y, ship.angle));
        if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP)
            ship.thrust();
        if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            ship.left();
        if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
            ship.right();
        if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_Q)
            play = false;
    };

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {

    };

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
    {

    };

};
```

Generic Class to hold objects

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class Coords
{
    public static double RAD = 0.0174532925;
    public static int xmax = 800;
    public static int ymax = 600;

    public double x     = 0.0;
    public double y     = 0.0;
    public double dx    = 0.0;
    public double dy    = 0.0;
    public double vel   = 0.0;
    public double size = 0.0;
    public double angle= 0.0;
    public double da    = 0.0;

    public Coords()
    {
    };

    public void reinit()
    {
        x       = 0.0;
        y       = 0.0;
        dx      = 0.0;
        dy      = 0.0;
        vel     = 0.0;
        size    = 0.0;
        angle   = 0.0;
        da      = 0.0;
    };

    public void rot()
    {


    };

    public boolean oob(int xmax, int ymax)
    {
        if((x < xmax) && (x > 0) && (y < ymax) && (y > 0))
            return true;
        return false;
    };

    public boolean hit(Coords in)
    {
        if((in.x + in.size > x) && (in.x < x + size) && (in.y + in.size > y) && (in.y < y + size))
            return true;
        return false;
    };

    public void tick()
    {
        x = (dx + x) % xmax;
        y = (dy + y) % ymax;
        angle = (angle + da) % 360;
    };
};
```

Space ship class

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.lang.Math;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class Ship extends Coords
{
    private ImageIcon imageIcon;
    private Image image;

    public Ship(double x_in, double y_in)
    {
        imageIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/ship.png"));
        image = imageIcon.getImage();

        x = x_in;
        y = y_in;
    };

    public void thrust()
    {
        dx = dx + (vel * Math.sin(angle * RAD));  //Move points based on speed
        dy = dy + (vel * Math.cos(angle * RAD));
    };

    public void left()
    {
        da--;
    };

    public void right()
    {
        da++;
    };

    public void draw(Graphics graphics)
    {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)graphics;
        g.rotate(angle);
        g.drawImage(image, (int)x, (int)y, null);
    };
};
```

Laser Class

```
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class Laser extends Coords
{
    private ImageIcon imageIcon;
    private Image image;

    public Laser(double x_in, double y_in, double angle_in)
    {
        imageIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/laser.png"));
        image = imageIcon.getImage();

        angle = angle_in;

        vel = 20;
    };

    public void draw(Graphics graphics)
    {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)graphics;
        g.rotate(angle);
        g.drawImage(image, (int)x, (int)y, null);
    };
};
```

Asteroid class

```
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.Random;

public class Rock extends Coords
{
    private ImageIcon imageIcon;
    private Image image;

    public Rock(double x_in, double y_in, double size_in)
    {
        imageIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/rock.png"));
        image = imageIcon.getImage();

        x = x_in;
        y = y_in;
        size = size_in;

        Random random = new Random();
        int r = random.nextInt();
        angle = r % 360;
        vel = r % 5;
    };

    public void draw(Graphics graphics)
    {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)graphics;
        g.rotate(angle);
        g.drawImage(image, (int)x, (int)y, null);
    };
};
```

Comment: 1) Don't block the Event Dispatching Thread, it will prevent the event queue from processing (amongst other things) repaint requests.  You need some kind of background thread that takes care of the movements and up-dating the game state and THEN updates the UI
2) Don't update the UI from any thread other then EDT
3) You might like to have a read through [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) to help you along

Comment: It's getting late tonight, but i'm going to read those tomorrow.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm about to head home, if I get a chance, I will have a closer look at see if I can provide more concrete suggestions ;)

Comment: If you're going to check it out again, let me know what you think of the structure of the program.  I'm kinda worried that i'm over doing it.  I just program on the side for fun. :D

Comment: Also, this is not complete yet, so alot of the logic is missing.  I've only put some back end stuff up and barely enough to draw some graphics.

Comment: Is all this code really needed for your question ?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a number of ways to approach this problem.  The biggest issue you're going to have is synchronizing the updates to prevent the model from begin updated while it's begin rendered.

### The Basics

In order to achieve a reasonable result, you're going to need a model, a view and a driver/controller.

The model is responsible for maintaining the state of the game assets.  The view is responsible for rendering the model to the screen and the controller is responsible for updating the model and view as well as coordinating the inputs.

You have these basic concepts setup, more or less.

Thinks I might change.

- I would favor [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) of the use of `KeyListener`s.  Key bindings overcome the limitations of the `KeyListener` when it comes to focus management
- Use a `JPanel` (or other similar container) instead of painting directly to any top level container (such as `JFrame` or `JApplet`).  This has a number of benefits, Swing containers are double buffered by default and you now have the choice of deployment by simply adding the game panel to a top level container of your choice.
- I would send key events to the controller from the game panel (instead of attaching the controller as a listener directly to the view).  This mostly a personal choice, but it provides you with the ability to queue incoming events and better control how those inputs are processed

Things you will need

- Your driver will need to be threaded.  This means that the driver will run within it's own `Thread`, out side of the Event Dispatching Thread.  This allows the UI to continue to be updated, while the driver is updating the model and preparing the output and processing the input.  The thread may be required to "wait" in order to maintain your frame rate (and allow the UI to paint itself) between cycles.

### To the screen and beyond

Getting your game to the screen is little more trickier then some might think.

The most basic method is simply to update the model and call `repaint` on the component responsible for painting it and then letting the renderer simply `paint` the model.

The problem with this approach is;

1. It's impossible to know when the paint will/is actually taking place
2. It's possible for the model to be changed WHILE the repaint is taking place, which will cause dirty paints and inconsistencies between the model and the view

What you need is some way to generate the view and have that view updated to the screen.

The basic idea would be to have the view generate a backing buffer (such as a `BufferedImage`) that the controller can request.  The controller would then update this buffer using the information from the model.  It would then request that the view update itself with this buffer.

The view would need to synchronize the request to ensure that the switch between virtual views is not performed within a paint cycle.

What this generally means is the controller is capable of producing a number of "updates" between paint cycles without effecting the view and the view should always be painting (as close as it can be) the latest "frame".

In order to synchronize the switch, you could use a protected code block (a code block within a `synchronized` statement).  The problem with this, is you would also need to `synchronize` the paint method, which is never a good idea.

Instead, you should use `SwingUtilities#invokeAndWait`.  This would be used to call the view's switch method, passing in the latest buffer.  This will ensure that the update request will occur within the Event Dispatching Thread, meaning that it is impossible for the the paint method to be running (as it also runs within the Event Dispatching Thread).  It also "stops" the controller while the switch is taking place.

I, personally, would setup a pool of `BufferedImage`s (generally two, but it need to have the ability to grow and shrink as needed).  The idea is, when the controller requests a "buffer", you pop the top most buffer of the queue and return it.  If none exist in the queue, you would create a new one and return that instead.

As the buffer is returned (and you switch them), you would then return this buffer to the queue.

I'd have some timer in the background that fired at regular intervals to clean up the pool (remove excess buffers) to ensure we're not chewing up memory unnecessarily, but that's just me ;)

Comment: Wow thanks a lot!  I'm in over my head.  I made something similar in c++ with opengl, but this is overwhelming.  Thanks you for you help and i'll start reading on this!

Comment: I was hoping to add an example, but I'm a little pressed for time :(